# What is the exclamation mark in the hero selection screen?

Tags: overwatch

When selecting a hero, there is an exclamation mark inside a circle just below their name (top-right corner). What does it mean? What happens if you press it?

[image: This one.]

Comment: have you tried to press the button?

Comment: @Scribblenautical no. Normally I would, but I am kind of scared by this one (weird, no context exclamation marks scream warning to me)

Comment: You think Blizzard would destroy your machine whenever you click that button? I don't understand

Comment: @bmarkham I was thinking that maybe it's some "report abuse" kind of button and didn't want to give any moderators extra work by calling an abuse accidentaly.

Comment: Could downvoters perhaps comment on what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Given that the answer is found simply by clicking on the button, this question does not appear to show the research effort we expect from good-quality posts. Why would it matter if it *was* a report abuse button? Have you ever seen such a feature without the need to fill out any additional information, such as who you actually wanted to report? For future reference, *don't be afraid to push the interesting button*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This button will give you an overview of that hero's abilities, what they do, and what buttons they are bound to. This is what it looks like for D.Va:

[image: D.Va's hero overview]

As you can see, the screen shows you D.Va's role, her two ultimate abilities, her three normal abilities, and her passive, as well as a general indication of how difficult she is to play on a scale from 1 to 3 stars, with 3 being the hardest.